# The space complexity of counting distinct element in a stream.

Tags: analysis, algorithms

Let $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in [m]$. We want to store all the distinct elements in the stream $a_1 \ldots a_n$.

The claim is that we can store all the item seen, and this requires $O(n log m)$ bit of space. I'm having trouble understanding.

So my rough idea is that $n$ is from the number of possible unique alphabet, and $log m$ is from doing binary search for each $a_i$, but I'm not exactly sure how binary search translates space bits.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each individual element $a_i$ can be identified using $O(\log m)$ space, as the universe has size $m$. In the worst case, all $n$ elements in the data stream are distinct and we need to memorize them all. As a result we get $O(n\log m)$ as space complexity.